# Puppeteer cannot breakpoint inside page.evaluate or page.$$eval

Tags: puppeteer

Using Puppeteer version: "9.0.0"

Unfortunately debugging in chrome dev tools does not work at all with this puppeteer version.
So I resorted to [NDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ndb).
Using NDB I can breakpoint anywhere apart from inside page.evaluate function and page.$$eval().

Running the script with ndb:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "ndb node startscrape.js"
 },
```

startscrape.js

```
( async () => {



const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
       
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport:null,
        slowMo: 250,
        devtools:true,
       
    });


        

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
await page.type('input', 'Here' );
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
await page.waitForNavigation();


let x = () => {
     debugger;
      console.log('can I debug here?') //YES - breakpoints work upon executing x();

 };

 x();


let xa = await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log('Alive'); // Logging works in console but cannot breakpoint
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someitem');
    return elements;
});

    // Cannot debug inside here too
// let xa = await page.$$eval('body', (body) => {
//     console.log('Alive');
//     let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('serp-item');
//     return elements;
// });


// breakpoint comes here 
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');


//await browser.waitForTarget(() => false);

  })();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the function arguments of `page.evaluate()` and similar ones are not executed per se: their serialized (stringified) code is transferred from the Node.js context into the browser context, then a new function is recreated from that code and executed there. That is why the breakpoints in the initial function have no effect on the recreated function.

Comment: So techincally if  I place a debugger; into that function and opened dev tools it should breakpoint?

Comment: @Phil15 I think it should.

Comment: Unfortunately I get another Puppeteer issue where the browser does not show any code at all.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67461958/puppeteer-evaluation-script-empty-in-chrome-dev-tools

 But I will mark this as an answer since its technically correct.