# __puppeteer_evaluation_script__ empty in Chrome dev tools

Tags: puppeteer

With Puppeteer version: "9.0.0"

When placing debugger into JavaScript code and launching puppeteer the source code is empty in chrome dev tools.

Running the script with Node:

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "node startscrape.js"
 },
```

startscrape.js

```
( async () => {



const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
    {
       
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport:null,
        slowMo: 250,
        devtools:true,
       
    });


        

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
await page.type('input', 'Here' );
await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
await page.waitForNavigation();



let xa = await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log('Alive'); // Logging works in console but cannot breakpoint
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someitem');
    return elements;
});


await page.goto('https://www.google.com');



  })();
```

Result: breakpoint triggers however no source code can be seen:
[image]

This is an issue in Puppeteer versions greater than "3.0.0" unfortunately version 3.0 is too old now

Comment: Did you try using `debugger`? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/debugging

Comment: yes, breakpoint gets hit in debugger, but source code is not seen in chromium window(as mentioned in original question)