# Debugger does not stop on breakpoint inside evaluate or $$eval (puppeteer debugging)

Tags: debugging, puppeteer

Running puppeteer with this arguments:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox"],
      headless: "false",
      devtools: "true",
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
      slowMo: 150,
    });
```

Puppeteer just jump over this function. If i put breakpoint exactly on the $$eval or evaluate function, debugger just go in some node code and does not go into my function at all. What i am doing wrong?

First example does not work:

```
const res = await page.evaluate((day) => {
      const div = day.querySelector("summary div div div");
      debugger;
      console.log(div);
    }, day);
```

Second example does not work either:

```
  const days = await page.$$eval(
  "main div section details",
  async (days, getMoonPhase) => {
    debugger;
    return await Promise.all(
      days.map(async (dayEl, dayIndex) => {
        // get just moon phase
        if (dayIndex === 0) {
          const moonPhase = await getMoonPhase(dayIndex);
          return { moonPhase };
        }

       ....a lot of other code...
          
        return allInfo;
      })
    );
  },
  await getMoonPhase(page)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far, as I know, evaluate method gets code from the function that is transferred from the Node.js context into the browser context, then a new function is created and executed in browser context, so setting breakpoint has no influence on actual function.

[Puppeteer cannot breakpoint inside page.evaluate or page.$$eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454406/puppeteer-cannot-breakpoint-inside-page-evaluate-or-page-eval)

If you will go through 'step into next function call' in browser debugger, it would actually execute each next line in eval one by one, so you can have analogue to breakpoints.

Comment: I did that and it wont go to eval argument function (which i gave him). It goes actually in some node code and not my function at all